# Java, Maven - file overwrites the data instead of appending the data to it

Tags: java, maven

I am working with `java`, `maven` and `cucumber` for testing. Here's the step definition I've. And the file `test.txt` is in `src/test/resources`. The file is empty.

```
public void store_ids() {
        String id = currentScenarioData.scenarioContext.getScenarioContext("ID").toString();
        try{
            String savestr = getClass().getResource("/test.txt").getFile().toString();
            System.out.println("::: savestr :::" + savestr);
            File intentFile = new File(savestr);

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(intentFile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);

            if ( intentFile.isFile() && !intentFile.isDirectory() ) {
                System.out.println("::: FILE EXISTS :::"); // this works
                out.println(id + "\n");
            }
            else {
                fw = new FileWriter(intentFile);
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

When I run a test case with `mvn clean verify` the file `test.txt` is at `target/test-classes` and it always gets overwritten with new data. The original file at `src/test/resources` remains empty.

If I run the same test case multiple times then I should have multiple lines of data written in a file. But the data in a file always gets overwritten and there is only one `ID` written in a file.

I think the issue is `target/test-classes` gets deleted and created again when I run with `mvn clean verify`. **How do I avoid this?**

**UPDATE**
Yes running `mvn` without `clean` keeps the file in `target/test-classes` and I got multiple lines of data written by running the test case multiple times. Is this the correct way?

**When I run test cases should I write data in a file in `resources` or in a file in `target`?**

**How do I append data into already exist file with respect to `maven` and `java`?**

Comment: could you clarify, do you want to write to file in resource dir or in target?

Comment: @ramazan file in `resource` is empty and I want to keep appending data into a file in `target` when I run testcases.

Comment: clean command delete target folder, you won't be able to save it there with command you use. You could run it like: ```mvn verify```, or write to file outside target

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you write in `target` is transient and gets deleted with next `mvn clean` - this is the answer to why it gets deleted. Now if you want this file for testing purposes where it will only be produced as a side effect and you don't need to keep the file afterwards, it's OK to put it under target, however if you want to gather some reports or keep the data, it should be put outside of target.

Why it gets generated under target? Because maven compiles your java sources and places all classes under that folder and then it uses it as a runtime classpath so anything generated, if it doesn't have an absolute path, will get generated relative to that location.

This line

`getClass().getResource("/test.txt")`

says - take the current class and it's location and create a file under that location. Now, of course that class is under `target/test-classes` so your file will be under `target/test-classes/test.txt` as expected

Comment: yes thank you for the explanation. So, where should I put `test.txt` considering it will be used in other test cases once it is filled with data?

Comment: create a special folder outside of target and put it there. It will most likely be some kind of absolute path of relative (`../../myfolder/test.txt`).

Answer (score -1):

In order to append text to a file you need to open file into append mode, you do it by using FileWriter, There is a special constructor for that which accepts a boolean argument to open the file in append mode.

I can see in else block you're not calling FileWriter constructor with argument true, which is needed to open file in append mode

steps to append text to a file in java

1. Open the file you want to append text using FileWriter in append mode by passing true
2. Wrap FileWriter into BufferedReader if you are going to write large text
3. Wrap PrintWriter if you want to write in new line each time
4. Close FileWriter in finally block to avoid leaking file descriptors

Try this code(JAVA6);

```
FileWriter fw = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null; 
PrintWriter pw = null;
  try { 
      fw = new FileWriter("<path-to-file>", true); 
      bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); 
      pw = new PrintWriter(bw); 
      pw.println("Shane");
      pw.println("Root");
      pw.println("Ben");
      System.out.println("Data Successfully appended into file");
      pw.flush(); 
    } 
    finally { 
        try { 
            pw.close();
            bw.close(); 
            fw.close(); 
            } 
        catch (IOException io) {// can't do anything 
    }
 }
```

Comment: I already tried this way from another source on internet. The issue is if I run test cases multiple times I should have multiple line of data written in a file. But it gets overwritten every time I run the test case.